# importing Magento database from wamp to a live server from

Tags: magento-2.1

I am trying to import my magento database to a live server from my wamp. I get the error as seen in the snapshot[image: database import error]

Comment: How are you exporting the database? That query is failing because you are missing the comment for the 2nd column.

Comment: @AndrewNoble Could you please put your comment as an answer. It is the real answer to this thread , I blieve

Answer (score 4):

By using this command line would make things a bit easier IMO.

Like this in Linux :

```
$ mysql -u root -p foodtrolley < /tmp/foodtrolley.sql;
Like this in Windows:

C:\> mysql -u root -p foodtrolley < c:\tmp\foodtrolley.sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

The SQL you are trying to import is invalid from the snippet you provided in the screenshot.

The first column is valid and has a comment set:

```
`notification_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Notification Id'
```

Your second column, on the other hand, is missing the comment:

```
`severity` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'MISSING COMMENT'
```

Default Magento sets the comment for that column to **'Problem type'**.

How are you exporting/importing the database? You might be better off exporting a SQL file, uploading it to the server, and importing it manually.